# rails error after bundle install and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm having trouble figuring out this problem since yesterday. So what happened is, after pulling from our repo what I did was, I did a `bundle install` and `bin/rake db:migrate` then after running the server I have this error. I also checked my senior's log on his server it doesn't have this. I tried uninstalling all gems and reinstalling them but the same issue. I also checked my `i18n` gem nothing suspicious

```
gem list | grep i18      
i18n (0.7.0)
i18n_data (0.10.0)
kaminari-i18n (0.5.0)
rails-i18n (4.0.9)
```

```
/home/raphaelgako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-06d935c66ac2/lib/spree_i18n/version.rb:11: warning: already initialized constant SpreeI18n::VERSION::MAJOR
/home/raphaelgako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-06d935c66ac2/lib/spree_i18n/version.rb:11: warning: previous definition of MAJOR was here
/home/raphaelgako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-06d935c66ac2/lib/spree_i18n/version.rb:12: warning: already initialized constant SpreeI18n::VERSION::MINOR
/home/raphaelgako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-06d935c66ac2/lib/spree_i18n/version.rb:12: warning: previous definition of MINOR was here
/home/raphaelgako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-06d935c66ac2/lib/spree_i18n/version.rb:13: warning: already initialized constant SpreeI18n::VERSION::TINY
/home/raphaelgako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-06d935c66ac2/lib/spree_i18n/version.rb:13: warning: previous definition of TINY was here
/home/raphaelgako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-06d935c66ac2/lib/spree_i18n/version.rb:15: warning: already initialized constant SpreeI18n::VERSION::STRING
/home/raphaelgako/.rbenv/versions/2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-06d935c66ac2/lib/spree_i18n/version.rb:15: warning: previous definition of STRING was here
```

my next step would be uninstalling `rbenv` if this doesn't work then I might have to reformat because I'm suspecting that I broke the system file. We're using Linux distro `Pop OS!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Gemfile have ruby and rails version. Also, you should've `.ruby-version` file on the root of your project.

Try these commands in the following order:

```
$ git clone your_repo.git
$ cd your_repo
$ bundle i
$ bundle exec rake db:create
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ rails s
```

If this works, then the problem was that you were using `rake` commands directly, instead of `bundle exec rake`.

Comment: Just occured, these lines are just `warnings`, not `errors`. If your app is not booting server then there might be something else. Did you look through whole logs?

Comment: hello. thank you for this. I already made changes I'm afraid I might lose my work. yea It's a warning but I don't want to commit this as I might break the production code.

Comment: You can test it on other temporary directory. Ex: `cd ../` -> `mkdir temp` -> `cd temp` and then you can see if the above works.

Comment: @aRtoo did you try it?

Comment: not yet my dude. but ill let you know for sure. thanks